# Excel diagram with time value or number on category ax

Tags: excel, time, diagram

I need to make a diagram which shows the lines of different ceramic firing schedules. I want them to be plotted in one diagram and they need to be plotted in time-relative ax. It needs to show the different durations in a right way. I don't seem to be able to achieve this.
What I have is the following:

**First table:**

| Pendelen | Temp. per uur | Stooktemp. | Stooktijd 4 | Stooktijd Cum.4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 95 | 120 | 1:15:47 | 1,26 |
|  | 205 | 537 | 2:02:03 | 3,30 |
|  | 80 | 620 | 1:02:15 | 4,33 |
|  | 150 | 1075 | 3:02:00 | 7,37 |
|  | 50 | 1196 | 2:25:12 | 9,79 |
| 10 |  | 1196 | 0:10:00 | 9,95 |
| Total |  |  | 9:57:17 |  |

**Second table:**

| Pendelen | Temp. per uur | Stooktemp. | Stooktijd 5 | Stooktijd Cum.5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 140 | 540 | 3:51:26 | 3,86 |
|  | 65 | 650 | 1:41:32 | 5,55 |
|  | 140 | 1095 | 3:10:43 | 8,73 |
|  | 50 | 1222 | 2:32:24 | 11,27 |
| Total |  |  | 11:16:05 |  |

[image]
The lines to be shown in a diagram should represent the 'stooktijd cum.' for both programs 4 and 5 (which is a cumulation of the time needed to fire up the kiln from it's previous temp. in the schedule). One should be able to see in the diagram that program 5 takes more time to reach it's endtemp.
What I achieved is nothing more than a diagram with two lines, but only plotted in the 'stooktijd cum.4' points from program 4. The image shows a screenshot of this diagram.

[image]

But as you can see, this doesn't look like program 5 takes more time to reach it's end. I would like it to show something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create this table :

|  | p4 | p5 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 |  | 10 |
| 3.86 |  | 540 |
| 5.55 |  | 650 |
| 8.73 |  | 1095 |
| 11.27 |  | 1222 |
| 0 | 0 |  |
| 1.26 | 120 |  |
| 3.3 | 537 |  |
| 4.33 | 620 |  |
| 7.37 | 1075 |  |
| 9.79 | 1196 |  |
| 9.95 | 1196 |  |

Select all > <kbd>F11</kbd> > Design > Chg Chart type > `scatter with straight line and marker`

Here's my tryout :
[image: sample output]

Please share if it works/not. ( :

Comment: It worked. I made it in a table where some calculations are made to get these times I need. For every new firingcurve I ad a column and change the chart-area to have the last column in it.